# ¿Como compartir las variables scss en otros componentes hijos con scss en m i proyecto de angular?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, scss

recurro a su sabiduria, quisiera saber como puedo compartir las variables que declare en scss en otros componentes de angular.

Tengo esta estructura de carpetas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el styles css que esta al lado sin problemas reconoce esas variables con la importacion

```
/* Importing Bootstrap SCSS file. */
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import './vars';
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700');
```

pero no me funciona en los componentes hijos , donde quiero usar la variable $main por ejemplo.
Supongo que puedo hacer importacion directa asy como en el styles, pero antes de eso quisiera saber si hay alguna forma mas elegante de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones.

**Añadir carpeta de estilos en angular.json**

Añadir la ruta de la carpeta donde los estilos en el fichero de configuración `angular.json`. Esto te permitirá importar los ficheros de scss en los componentes de angular.

```
{
    ...
    "apps": [{
        "root": "src",
        ...
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
            "includePaths": [
              "./scss"
            ]
        }

    }]
}
```

Ahora imagina que tienes un componente llamado `hello.component.ts` y en el `hello.component.scss` tienes lo siguiente. Esto te permite acceder a las variables.

```css
@import "vars"; // importas el fichero de variables

h1 {
    color: $main;
}
```

**Importar directamente el fichero de estilos**

Esto tiene el inconveniente de que la ruta será distinta en función de la ubicación del componente dentro del proyecto.

```css
@import "../../scss/vars"; // ruta al fichero de variables

h1 {
    color: $main;
}
```

[Artículo completo](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-shortcut-to-importing-styles-files-in-components)

Answer (score 2):

Una forma sería como indicas, importando el fichero de variables en cada componente que quieras utilizar.

También podemos utilizar :root{} para encapsular las variables a nivel global, y reutilizarlas más adelante con var(--variable)

Por ejemplo, en tu archivo de variables:

```
:root{
  --purple: #a434eb;
}
```

Después en el componente:

```
.clase-custom {
   background-color: var(--purple)
}
```

Espero sea de ayuda,

Un saludo